# hide a span with text in odoo, wanna hide the span element in xml file?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In Leads after Contact name Title is coming and in between them one comma is there as ,

```
<span attrs="{'invisible': [('title', '=', '')]}">, </span>
```

I want to move Title before the Contact Name, and hide this comma.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="title" position="replace">
</field>
<span attrs="{'invisible': [('title', '=', '')]}" position="replace">
</span>
<field name="contact_name" position="before">
     <field name="title" placeholder="Title" domain="[('domain', '=', 'contact')]" class="oe_inline" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
     <span attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('title', '=', ''),('title', '=', False)]}">, </span>
</field>
```